# Angular8 dropdown value not binding on page load

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a location dropdown with its options coming from api result. I have model which is set if value is already saved before.

```
            <select id="location" [(ngModel)]="location" name="location">
              <option value="">Select Location </option>                  
              <option *ngFor="let data of locationType" [ngValue]="data.locationId">{{data.locationValue}}</option>                  
           </select>
```

I am setting location model on `ngOnInit`, the value is stored is location storage when user login

```
this.location=localStorage.locationId;
```

[image]
[image]

When the page is loaded, the model is populated in dropdown inspite of model having the locationId, it get binds only after multiple click on the page

I am unable to understand the behaviour, why is it happening so, any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: Do you see any errors in developer tools? (CTRL + SHIFT + I), Also, did you try to use value instead of ngValue? (ngValue usually used for objects and not strings)

Comment: @Erez.S , thanks using value did the trick, also thanks for the info, i was not aware of it,

Comment: Great! Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, when using string as an option value, you should use `value` instead of `ngValue`

Answer (score 0):

If `locationId` type is `Number` then you need to convert it when reading from `localStorage` because it always returns `string`.

```
this.location=localStorage.locationId ? parseInt(localStorage.locationId, 10) : null;
```